# How to assert two dictionaries in python in radish framework?

Tags: python, testing, bdd

Now i have two dictionaries and i want to check if they are equal.

I have tried `assert dict1 == dict2`

```
@steps
class Calculator:
    def step_impl_antenna(self, step, cell, antenna):
        """Invoke client and get the data cell_plan {cell:cell} antenna {antenna:antenna}"""
        print("Step")
        expected_cell =  literal_eval(cell) #expected_cell={"hello" : "123" }
        cell_plan_data = {"hello" : "123" }
        assert cell_plan_data == expected_cell
        print("")
```

I want to assert two dictionaries in radish frame work.

Comment: That looks like it should work.  What went wrong, exactly?

Comment: There is assert error. I have tried extending class with **unittest.Testcase** but that is not supported in radish so just wondering if there is any other way out